# My regex works fine with one line of input, but don't with two or more...

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I'm working on this small code: http://jsfiddle.net/5kXBk/
If you type "foo $42 bar" in the first div, you get the correct text coloration. But if you add a new line and start writing, the text remains green...

How can I solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `^` and `$` in your RegExp. This causes the RegExp to only match only one string: a string which fully matches the pattern.

Use the following RE instead, at **fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kXBk/7/**

```
text = text.replace(/([^$]*)((?\$\d+)*)(.*?)(?=<br|$)/g, "<span class=\"blue\">$1</span><span class=\"red\">$2</span><span class=\"green\">$3</span>");
```

1. `([^$]*)` Any non-dollar sign
2. ((?:\$\d+)*) Any "A dollar sign with at least one number"
3. `(.*?)` Any character
4. `(?=<br|$)` Before an end (`<br>` or `$`) (`contentEditable` converts newlines into `<br>`s)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 14 and new line becomes div, so you'd want to check `(?=<br|<div|$)`

Comment: And in Opera a newline becomes '</p><br><p>'. Perhaps a textarea should be used for the text input to get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the m (multiline) flag besides the g (global) flag ?

Here is a link that might help: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Eg: /regexp/gm

Comment: The problem is that the div is `contenteditable` and returns HTML tags instead of newlines, so this wouldn't work.